# How to add element inside ListItem in code behind?

Tags: c#, asp.net, bulletedlist

I want to add something like this in the code behind:

```
<ul>
   <li><a>A</a></li>
</ul>
```

However, the ListItem of ASP.NET seems to allow text only:

```
BulletedList UserSubMenuList = new BulletedList();
ListItem EditUserItem = new ListItem("Edit Profile");
```

Is there other way to add content between `<li></li>` tag with code behind rather then using HtmlGenericControl?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Front :

```
<ul id="test" runat="server">

</ul>
```

Back:

```
Label label1=new Label();

label1="test";

test.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl("<li>")); 

test.Controls.Add(label1); 

test.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl("</li>"))
```

Comment: Heh. Just what I was about to post. Peoples forget that you don't always have to use ASP.NET server controls in an ASP.NET page... :]

Comment: How do the literal controls get inserted into the correct place in the DOM?

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
BulletedList UserSubMenuList = new BulletedList();
UserSubMenuList.Items.Add(new ListItem(HttpUtility.HtmlEncode(@"<a href=\"link\">Edit Profile</a>"));
```

Note that you'll be clearing whatever was initially displayed if you do the first line (the constructor).

The Text property is simply the string of text to put in the `<li>` tags - if it's text (like all HTML markup), it should be able to go there.