# add image tag through code behind in list

Tags: c#, html

I want to add image tag from code behind.It is rendering as `<img src='Admin\Images\42\O_1.jpg'/>` but I want image instead of it . Thanks

```
 var tmpRBL = new BulletedList();
    var tmpItem = new ListItem("<img src='" + ImageUrl + "'/>", column.ColumnName.Split('_')[2]);                                        
    tmpRBL.Items.Add(tmpItem);
```

Comment: Something not clear. You say it is rendering as `<img>` but you want "image" instead. What do you mean by "image"?

Comment: Yes I want to show image but it is showing tag as it is .

Comment: I got it .https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7226546/how-to-add-element-inside-listitem-in-code-behind